# How do I display the Country name, State name, and City name instated of Id in excel sheet while export?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, phpexcel

I have a record in the table which are

```
Name | Mobile     | Country | State | City
XYZ  | 0123456789 | 231     | 3921  | 42737
mnb  | 0125415245 | 13      | 269   | 6602
lkh  | 9874525415 | 231     | 3939  | 44668
```

Now I am using CodeIgniter. I am exporting the data in excel sheet using PHPExcel

Controller:

```
public function export_order_list() {
    $object = new PHPExcel();
    $object->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $table_columns = array("Name","Mobile","Country","State","City");
    $column = 0;
    $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('1:1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    foreach($table_columns as $field) {
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 1, $field);
        $column++;
    }
    $export_list = $this->Customer_model->export_order_list_model();//getting all records
    $excel_row = 2;
    foreach($export_list as $row) {
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, $row->Name);
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $excel_row, $row->Mobile);
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $excel_row, $row->Country);
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $excel_row, $row->State);
        $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $excel_row, $row->City);
        $excel_row++;
    }

    $object_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="list.xls"');
    $object_writer->save('php://output');
}
```

Model:

```
public function export_order_list_model(){
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('tbl_customer');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    if($result) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am getting the output.

[image]

Now My issue is How do I display the Country name, State name and City name instated of Id?

I need an output like this

[image]

I have all the countries, state and city name in the database and column name of the tables are

```
Country
id |country_name

State
id| state_name |country_id

City
id |cities_name|state_id
```

**Update:**

Please check my query is correct for this output? Because It's not working for me.

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('tbl_customer');
$this->db->join('Country', 'Country.id=tbl_customer.c_b_country');
$this->db->join('State', 'State.id=tbl_customer.c_b_state'); 
$this->db->join('City', 'City.id=tbl_customer.c_b_city');
```

Comment: You need to `JOIN` the necessary tables in your query, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: @jeroen, Thanks for the information, I tried to join but there is some confusion. I will share you the query

Comment: Maybe `from table as t join country as c on c.id = t.country_id join state as s on t.state_id = s.id join city as c on t.city_id = c.id` or you could join from the `city` and use its`state_id` and then the states `country_id`.

Comment: $this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('tbl_customer');$this->db->join('Country', 'Country.id=tbl_customer.c_b_country');
$this->db->join('State', 'State.id=tbl_customer.c_b_state');
$this->db->join('City', 'City.id=tbl_customer.c_b_city');  is it correct? because it's not working for me

Comment: @user3783243, I updated the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is correct for codeigniter. Haven't worked with that framework. Does `select * from tbl_customer
join Country 
on Country.id = tbl_customer.c_b_country
join State
on State.id = tbl_customer.c_b_state
join City
on City.id=tbl_customer.c_b_city` give back a result in your DB interface?

Comment: @user3783243, Give me some time to understand your query.

Comment: @user3783243, You query is working I check on MySQL but In the controller country, _name is not displaying

Comment: When you bring it into codeigniter or on the DB? If codeigniter trying looking at your returned array with `print_r` sometimes the index names get mangled when aliases aren't used.

Answer (score 1):

Your raw SQL query should look as follows:

```
SELECT 
  cu.name AS Name, 
  cu.mobile AS Mobile,
  c.country_name AS Country
  s.state_name AS State,
  ct.cities_name AS City
FROM tbl_customer cu
  JOIN Country c ON cu.Country = c.id
  JOIN State s ON cu.State = s.id
  JOIN City ct ON cu.City = ct.id;
```

There's a few things going on there:

- Join every table with data you plan on using
- In your select you must reference the column as it appears in the joined table
- Removed the `select *` which would end up pulling ambigious fields like "id" in multiple places
- Used the AS keyword to rename the columns into what you've used in your code

Try running this raw query in your DB directly to ensure it does what you expect. After that it's just a case of formatting it back into your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This query will work.

```
$this->db->select("name,mobile,country,state,city");
$this->db->from('customer');
$this->db->join('country', 'country.id=customer.country_id','left');
$this->db->join('state', 'state.id=customer.state_id','left'); 
$this->db->join('city', 'city.id=customer.city_id','left');
```